# DataTables warning: table id='getTestCaseTable' - Requested unknown parameter 'dbi' for row 17, column 0

Tags: jquery, datatables, create-table

I am using datatable in my widget and getting above error, tried different approaches but couldn't solve my problem yet, please help ...

Web service response is

```
{
    Message: "Related objects for dbi"
    Success: true
    data: [ {
        dbi: "node1", 
        type: "String", 
        name: "Air Craft", 
        revision: "1", 
        current: "design"
    }]
}
```

Widget JavaScript code

```
function call  
myWidget.createGetTestCasesTable(data.data);

function definition 
createGetTestCasesTable: function (data) {
            getTestCasesTable = $('#getTestCaseTable').DataTable( {
                data: data,
                "paging": true,
                columns: [
                    { data: 'dbi' },
                    { data: 'type' },
                    { data: 'name' },
                    { data: 'revision' },
                    { data: 'current' }
                ]
            });
        }
```

This works fine, but while adding new row ->

```
updateDataTable: function(data){
 getTestCasesTable.row.add( [                
                data.dbi, data.type, data.name, data.revision, data.current
            ] ).draw();
}
```

this is giving me datatable warning

```
DataTables warning: table id=getTestCaseTable - Requested unknown parameter 'dbi' for row 17, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

Please let me know if you know the cause

Thanking you in advance!!

Comment: The error message refers to `DevelopmentBacklogItem`, the question's title refers to `dbi`. Neither of these parameter names appear anywhere in the code you have provided. Based on that, I'm not sure if anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: actually it is same I just renamed it , dbi and DevelopmentBacklogItem is same

Comment: What are the contents of data.dbi when adding a new row. One of the many items associated with the error message you're getting is that the data attempting to be displayed is not displayable given the parameters of the table.

Comment: all are string data.dbi = "Development Backlog Item00000331"

this is response of my service request

it comes like this ->

{
    Message: "Related objects for dbi"
    Success: true
    data: [ {
        dbi: "Development Backlog Item00000331", 
        type: "String", 
        name: "Air Craft", 
        revision: "1", 
        current: "design"
    }]
}